# How to turn on XML attribute inspector

Tags: android, xml

I recently disabled the XML attribute inspector that would prompt messages such as the below in the XML in real time before running the app. Now since I disabled it I am only able to see the errors when I run my app.

[image]

How can i turn on the instant "Attribute inspector" back on?

It would be displayed as a red light bulb to the left of the XML such as:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections
```

Press on "reset" at the upper right corner, or if it is not there, then search for "xml" and check the appropriate fields according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

File>Setting>Editor>Code style>Inspection>

Try checking/unchecking some Android>Lint>...